# APScheduler process not working with heroku/django set up

Tags: python, django, heroku, apscheduler

I'm having problems getting my APScheduler process on Heroku working with a Django environment.

What I did was create a management command so that my apscheduler jobs had access to my Django environment.

**appname/management/commands/scheduler.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
  """
  Management command for APScheduler
  """

  def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
    sched = Scheduler()

    @sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=0, minute=0)
    def a_weekly_job():
      run_some_code()

    sched.start()
    print "Scheduler started"

    while True:
      pass
```

I set up my Procfile to the following (for the scheduler process)

```
scheduler: python manage.py scheduler
```

However, when I deploy my application with the scheduler process, I get the following warning message and my job does not run:

```
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Run time of job "a_weekly_job" (trigger: cron[day_of_week='mon-sun', hour='23', minute='25'], next run at: 2013-09-24 23:25:00)" was missed by 0:00:07.261174
```

How do I get the job to run?

Answer (score 0):

add clock.py file:

```
sched = Scheduler()

@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=0, minute=0)
def a_weekly_job():
  run_some_code()

sched.start()
print "Scheduler started"

while __name__ == '__main__':
  pass
```

Procfile:

```
web: ...
clock: python clock.py --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: i don't have access to the django environment with this method.

Comment: Weird, I'm able to use any class from env packages both on heroku and locally. Did you started the env before run the script? Also you can use 'foreman start' command.

Answer (score -1):

Use a subprocess to run "python manage.py scheduler":

```
import subprocess
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour=0, minute=0)
def scheduler_sample():
    subprocess.call('python manage.py scheduler'), shell=True, close_fds=True)

sched.start()
```